# How to understand ""A block is never divided across multiple MPs."?

Tags: cuda

For CUDA, I understand that "A block is never divided across multiple MPs." (http://llpanorama.wordpress.com/2008/06/11/threads-and-blocks-and-grids-oh-my/).

Just to test for this, I assigned an extremely large block size to the kernel:

```
__global__ void dummy()
{
}

int main()
{
        int N=21504*40000; //21504 is the total threads I found for my Tesla M2070
        dim3 grids(1,2);
        dim3 thres(N,N);
        dummy<<<grids,thres>>>();
        return 0;
}
```

However, there is no compilation or runtime error, and not sure what was going on...

Comment: How can you say there are no runtime errors when you code doesn't check for them?

Comment: Instead of referencing a random outdated page on the internet by someone who blogs while he is trying to learn CUDA himself, I'd strongly recommend reading the definite source of information, which is the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) by Nvidia. It it well written and contains everything you need to know to write CUDA programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add cudaGetLastError() after the dummy<<<>>> call, you'll get a CUDA Launch Failure error (you can convert an error code to a string using cudaGetErrorString(err_code)).

Comment: You need to synchronize after the kernel call to get error code.

Comment: @Eugene: No, not in this case you won't. The kernel launch should return `cudaErrorInvalidConfiguration`, and that will be available via `cudaPeekAtLastError` or `cudaGetLastError` immediately after the runtime API launch statement.

Answer (score 0):

These error are not compile error and you will face to the run-time error after run. To understand the sentence, you should understand the architecture. It is designed to fasten the communication of threads which are placed in the same thread-block thorough shared memory of one MP (SM). So, they are all resident in the same SM and are not dispatched.